# Iteration of date field crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, iteration, formula-editor

Im pretty new to crystal reporting ,I need a formula to to iterate through the date field.All it took is a date field as dynamic input-{?startdate} 
I need the page should display 30 days/date from that dates in reports..(I got to display other data to pull in between these date fielded captions.)This is a quick requirement ,I know i should have made some investigation before posting here..Any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: So you want everything between your start date and 30 days from that date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two things:

1. Set your date parameter to allow for range values (user enters start date and end date)
2. Add 30 days to the day of your chosen date `datefield in [{?startdate}, DateAdd('d', 30, {?startdate})]`

Hope that helps,

Chris